# Why doesn't the EmailValidator fail on a TextFields empty value?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to validate a `TextField` to pass for a valid email address and to fail if the entered `String` is an invalid address or just empty.

As written in the [API docs](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/validator/EmailValidator.html), the validation should fail if the TextFields value is empty, as long as its `required` property is set to true.

So, i tried it with the following code:

```
//TextField as part of a signup form. flSignupForm is an instance of FormLayout
TextField tfEmail=new TextField("Email");
tfEmail.addValidator(new EmailValidator("The email address isn't valid."));
tfEmail.setRequired(true);
tfEmail.setRequiredError("The email field is required. You'll need it to log in.");
flSignupForm.addComponent(tfEmail);
```

What i get is an Exception, but i want to get a little red mark in front of the `TextField` if nothing's written just like i get it when the entered address is invalid. What can i change?

Btw: I'm using Vaadin 7.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should better create your forms by [Binding Fields to Items](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.itembinding.html). In this case, binder catches an exeption from EmailValidator and marks TextField with error after commit().

At second, if you move pointer over the TextField and see a pop-up error but component looks the same, it means that TextField hasn't container. This is because [error Indicator (exclamation mark) are actually provided by the layouts containing the component, not the component themselves.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965015/2535129) You should wrap TextField in any container.

I usually mark error fields in my own way with CSS styles. For example, TextField with error has CSS style "v-textfield-error" and you can define new rule as

```
.v-textfield-error  {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(256, 0, 0, .5);
    outline: 1px solid rgb(256, 0, 0);
}
```

as example. And it looks better than an indicator and always works.